# How to Create an Empty Html.DropDownlistFor & how to disable Html.TextBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I have the following code inside my asp.net mvc view:-

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FirewallCustomer.CustomerVLANSID,null, null, null)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirewallCustomer.CustomerName)
<div><span class="f">VLAN IP</span> @Html.TextBox("VLANIP", new { disabled = "disabled"})</div>
```

but the above code will raise an error on the DropDownListFor:-

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that
>   has the key 'FirewallCustomer.CustomerVLANSID'.

and for the TexBox it will show the `disabled = "disabled"`  inside the textbox body, instead of disabling it. can anyone adivce on how to solve my dropdownlist & my textbox problems???
Thanks`

Comment: in DropDownListFor try passing an empty values list, but not null

Comment: for TextBox: read its conctructor signature, you're putting html attribtes in the wrong place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- For textbox

`@Html.TextBox("VLANIP", new { disabled = "disabled"})` change to

`@Html.TextBox("VLANIP","Your Value", new { disabled = "disabled"})` . I would like to advise you change disabled = "disabled" to @readonly = "readonly".

- For dropdown list, if you wanna create a empty dropdownList for, you have to convert you FirewallCustomer.CustomerVLANSID to SelectListItem and add empty value for it. Please post your action for this view, i can help you. Should try

  `Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FirewallCustomer.CustomerVLANSID,Enumerable.Empty< SelectListItem >(),null)`